# jQuery load HTML with images renders errors into console

Tags: jquery, html, image, parsing, exception

When I'm trying to load simple piece of html (with some images, but not accessible right now) jQuery for some reason tries to load them, and produces error into console.

here is the sample code:

```
var html = $('<div>' + '<img src="http://not.found/1.jpg"/>' + '</div>');
```

Here is the error:

```
GET http://not.found/1.jpg  jquery-2.0.3.js:5788
x.extend.buildFragment jquery-2.0.3.js:5788
x.extend.parseHTML jquery-2.0.3.js:493
x.fn.x.init jquery-2.0.3.js:127
x jquery-2.0.3.js:63
(anonymous function)
InjectedScript._evaluateOn
```

How to prevent jQuery from trying to load images from html?

Comment: If you don't want it to be fetched, then I believe you may have to leave out the src attribute.

Comment: I just need to parse some piece of existing html string (let say 500 lines of code). You all are looking for workarouds which are not solving original problem - jQuery LOADS images during HTML PARSING. I believe it's wrong behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It is a "feature" of document fragment used to parsing HTML. You need to implement (or use) some another parser, not jQuery.

Both code samples generate error message due to failed load (Chrome 28).

```
(function () {
    var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://not.found/1.jpg";
    docFragment.appendChild(img);
}());

(function () {
    var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    docFragment.appendChild(div);
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="http://not.found/1.jpg"/>';
}());
```

PS: Trick with `insertAdjacentHTML` does the same

Answer (score 0):

jQuery - is DOM manipulator, but not HTML strings parser.

In order to perform any actions, jQuery always converts passed string into DOM, thus triggering images downloads.

You should look into libraries that are pure-HTML strings parsers and doesn't require conversion into DOM.

For example http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/ (from John Resig)
OR https://npmjs.org/package/htmlparser

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

1. use a var to storage the src and assign an id to the image

   `var src="http://not.found/1.jpg"`;
2. create your html var

   `var html = $('<div>' + '<img id="imgid" />' + '</div>');`
3. add the property scr to the image

   `jQuery("#imgid").attr('src',src );`

Comment: I don't know the 'broken' srcs or how many image tags in HTML at all.
Just have a portion of ALREADY EXISTING HTML and need to PARSE IT WITHOUT EXCEPTIONS.

Thus this answer doesn't solve the described problem.